# Pine script: Exiting a strategy 5 mins. before market close

Tags: pine-script

I want to enter a strategy during 0915-1500 hrs and close the strategy 5 mins before the close at 15:20 as I do not want to have overnight exposure. I tried the following code but when I run the strategy, it exit only at 09:15

```
  
inSession (sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess)) == false

tradingTime = input(title="Trading time", type=input.session,defval="0915-1500")
preMarket = input(title="Pre Market period", type=input.session,defval="0000-0914")
postMarket = input(title="Post Market period", type=input.session,defval="1521-2400")

isTradingTime = inSession (tradingTime)
isClosingTime = inSession (preMarket) or inSession (postMarket)

if isTradingTime 
     go_long := 1

if (go_long and isClosingTime)
    exit_long := 1

strategy.entry("L", strategy.long,when=go_long)
strategy.close("L", when=exit_long)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to get something like this and i got the solution to my own question you can look into this link, this may be helpful.
[entering trade 'n' seconds before close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66333944/14828615)
In order to get 5m early exit change 5second in input to 300seconds.

Once you study the answer in this link you will be able to do it.