# How to delay alerts generated in pine script

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5

I send two Alert at the same time in one minute timeframe
I want to make a 3seconds delay between two signals

```
//@version=5
strategy('Strat with time delay', overlay=true)


ma = ta.sma(close, 100)
goLong = ta.crossover(close, ma)
goShort = ta.crossunder(close, ma)




plot(ma, 'MA', goLong ? color.lime : color.red)

if goShort and strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.close(id='Enter Long')

if goLong and strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.close(id='Enter Short')



if goLong
    strategy.entry('Enter Long', strategy.long)



if goShort
    strategy.entry('Enter Short', strategy.short)
```

The following solution did not work properly : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332133/how-to-delay-alerts-generated-in-pine-script-can-anyone-help-in-delaying-alerts)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help
https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-implement-a-time-delay-between-orders

You can use this to implement a 3 seconds delay between 2 events